# Object-level Restrictions not working (Facebook App)

Tags: facebook, restriction, country

As described [-here-](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/user-restrictions/) I wanted to restrict an app so that it's accessible from just one country using the following tag, but it's not working, I can access the App from Switzerland (CH). Any idea what the problem could be?

```
<meta property="og:restrictions:country:allowed" content="DE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The object level restrictions apply to Open Graph content, not applications. I presume you were trying to add the meta tag to html content in the app.

From a bug filed on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/343431899129688/